# What am I doing wrong with passing Rectangle to setContent in javafx 2?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2, java-7

I'm using javafx 2.2 with JDK 7 in Netbeans 7, with a code

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200, 200);
tab_1.setContent(r);
```

which gives me `error: rectangle cannot be converted to node.`
The `tab_1` is a [`Tab`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContent%28javafx.scene.Node%29) instance.

According to [the 2 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html), Rectangle is a subclass of `Node`.

Searching for similar problems only gave me the following SO question which I believe is unrelated: [JavaFX error: incompatible types - Object cannot be converted to Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056648/javafx-error-incompatible-types-object-cannot-be-converted-to-node)

In my understanding `Rectangle` is a `Node`, thus usable with `setContent`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct import: you should have `javax.scene.shape.Rectangle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
```

Its unlikely anything other than a wrong import is causing this.